# Can we use cocoa httpserver in ipad?

Tags: cocoa, ipad, cocoahttpserver

I want to know whether we can use cocoa http server in iPad? has anyone tried using cocoa http server in iPad? I don't want to host that as a server. The main purpose of the app is to communicate between a html file and Objective-C using the cocoa server.

Comment: Can you maybe clarify: _"to communicate between a html file and Objetive-c using the Cocoa server."_ CocoaHTTPServer is probably not the best solution in your case.

Comment: @Anne: Do you have any idea? actually both objective c and html will reside in the ipad only.

Comment: @Anne: can you suggest any other way?

Comment: Before I can make proper suggestions, I need to know what you mean by  _"communicate between a html file and Objetive-C"_. Please explain. Running a web-server is only necessary in rare cases, for example running specific audio-streams locally. Doing stuff with HTML files generally doesn't require any web-server.

Comment: @Anne: We are porting out application to ipad. Our application is currently a flash based application which communicates to servlets through a jetty server the whole set up is in the client side.Finally the servlets send the request to the application server which is the server. Now we are converting the swf to html. So we need to use those client side servlets too. Since java is not supported we have to use objective C . SO now the html file will call this objective c functions through ajax call and finally the objective c will call the app server. This is the requirement.

Comment: @Anne: this is the reason. I am trying to right the client side servlet part in app server itself. But this will lead to a major performance problem that's why I want to know whether i can use any http server in ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) runs on iOS and will run on iPad.